# Run testthat's `test_that`s within a script

Tags: r, testthat

When I write simple and quick code, possibly for exploration or helping others in debugging, I would love to test my code and share my tests with my peers.

Setup a complete {testthat} environment is not that hard to do, but it has a high friction in sharing the results. Moreover, for a rapid exploration, having everything in a single script could help understand all the ideas and mental processes leading to the solution. That could also help share snippets in chats, e.g., TG/WA/... .

My current solution is to set up the following two scripts during development and share `code.R`'s content (or file) at the end.

```r
## myproj/code.R
# code ---------------------
if (fun_1() + fun_2() == 3) {
  message("good job")
}

# funs ---------------------
fun_1 <- function() 1  # OK
fun_2 <- function() 3  # KO

# tests --------------------
test_that("fun_1 works", {
  expect_equal(fun_1(), 1)
})
test_that("fun_2 works", {
  expect_equal(fun_2(), 2)
})
```

```r
## myproj/run_tests.R
testthat::test_file("code.R")
```

My question is: there is a way to run all the `test_that`s tests in the local session within the current global environment, so that everything will be self-contained (even the option to run all the tests), and one (e.g., me) can run all the tests in a single key-stroke combination resulting in the standard {testthat} reporter's output?

I'm thinking about something like the following.

```r
## myproj/code.R
# code ---------------------
if (fun_1() + fun_2() == 3) {
  message("good job")
}

# funs ---------------------
fun_1 <- function() 1  # OK
fun_2 <- function() 3  # KO

# tests --------------------
with_reporter(default_reporter(), {
  test_that("fun_1 works", {
    expect_equal(fun_1(), 1)
  })
  test_that("fun_2 works", {
    expect_equal(fun_2(), 2)
  })
})
```

But it works if all tests pass only.

Note: selecting and running only

```r
test_that("fun_2 works", {
  expect_equal(fun_2(), 2)
})
```

works perfectly fine, providing the information about the error.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `default_reporter`, using `check_reporter` works fine:

```r
## myproj/code.R
library(testthat)

# code ---------------------
if (fun_1() + fun_2() == 3) {
  message("good job")
}
#> Error in fun_1(): could not find function "fun_1"

# funs ---------------------
fun_1 <- function() 1  # OK
fun_2 <- function() 3  # KO

# tests --------------------
with_reporter(check_reporter(), {
  test_that("fun_1 works", {
    expect_equal(fun_1(), 1)
  })
  test_that("fun_2 works", {
    expect_equal(fun_2(), 2)
  })
})
#> == Failed tests ================================================================
#> -- Failure (<text>:19:5): fun_2 works ------------------------------------------
#> fun_2() not equal to 2.
#> 1/1 mismatches
#> [1] 3 - 2 == 1
#> 
#> [ FAIL 1 | WARN 0 | SKIP 0 | PASS 1 ]
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Session info

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> - Session info ---------------------------------------------------------------
#>  setting  value
#>  version  R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
#>  os       Windows 10 x64 (build 22523)
#>  system   x86_64, mingw32
#>  ui       RTerm
#>  language (EN)
#>  collate  English_United States.1252
#>  ctype    English_United States.1252
#>  tz       Europe/Berlin
#>  date     2021-12-27
#>  pandoc   2.14.0.3 @ C:/Bin/RStudio/bin/pandoc/ (via rmarkdown)
#> 
#> - Packages -------------------------------------------------------------------
#>  package     * version date (UTC) lib source
#>  cli           3.1.0   2021-10-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  crayon        1.4.2   2021-10-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  desc          1.4.0   2021-09-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  digest        0.6.29  2021-12-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  evaluate      0.14    2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  fastmap       1.1.0   2021-01-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  fs            1.5.2   2021-12-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  glue          1.6.0   2021-12-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  highr         0.9     2021-04-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  htmltools     0.5.2   2021-08-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  knitr         1.37    2021-12-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  magrittr      2.0.1   2020-11-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  pkgload       1.2.4   2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  R6            2.5.1   2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  reprex        2.0.1   2021-08-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  rlang         0.4.12  2021-10-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  rmarkdown     2.11    2021-09-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  rprojroot     2.0.2   2020-11-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  rstudioapi    0.13    2020-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  sessioninfo   1.2.2   2021-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  stringi       1.7.6   2021-11-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  stringr       1.4.0   2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  testthat    * 3.1.1   2021-12-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  withr         2.4.3   2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  xfun          0.29    2021-12-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#>  yaml          2.2.1   2020-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.1.1)
#> 
#>  [1] C:/Bin/R/R-4.1.2/library
#> 
#> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Moreover, I have just discovered that if I write tests on a script, in RStudio, a button appears to facilitate the testing:

[image]